# What causes an invalid keycode error in Crystal Reports 13 (2010)?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I recently installed a new version of Crystal Reports 13 (2010) on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

When I add a new report item to the project, I get this message box error: "Invalid Keycode" and the project breaks down and the solution can't be used again (build or run).

I'm using the full .Net framework 4.0 (not client profile) as target framework.

Any idea what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uninstall  "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 - Beta x" and install latest version. You can download it from  [here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe.). 
Or change your system's date to a back date.